# Mathematically, why does spontaneous symmetry breaking occur?

Tags: potential, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking, electroweak

I think that: the Higgs potential is a function

$$V: \mathbb{C}^2 \times (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
where the parameters $(0, \infty)$ are the energy scales.

Then, for each $E \in (0, \infty)$ energy scale, we have a family of Higgs fields $H^E : \mathbb{R}^{1,3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$, where $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ is the spacetime and the requirement is that $H^E$ minimize $V(z, E)$, i.e,

$$V(H^E(x), E) \leq V(z, E), \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}^2, x \in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}.$$

When the energy scale is $E \approx v= 246$ GeV (vacuum expectation value), then the Higgs potential approximate to the usual form that we know

$$V(z, E \approx v) \approx \lambda(E) |z|^2 - \mu(E) |z|^4,$$
where $\lambda(v) > 0, \mu(v)>0$.

The Higgs fields $H^v$ for this energy have symmetry $U(1)$. This isn't the full symmetry, so this break the symmetry of the theory.

My questions:

Is the formulation correct?

If it is, what is the shape of the Higgs field for other energies? Is the same, the only things that change are the $\lambda, \mu$?